# parametro master=None dentro da classe no modulo tkinter (python)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Estou aprendendo o modulo tkinter no curso do professor Neri Neitzke, porêm, eu não entendi para que serve o parametro ( master=None ) no `__init__(self, master=None)` da classe abaixo, alguêm poderia me explicar qual a funcionalidade desse parametro na classe?, segue o código abaixo:

```
from tkinter import *


class App(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None): #esse parametro, para que serve?
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.criarBotoes()
        self.criarLabels()
        self.entradaDados()

    def criarBotoes(self):
        # primeira forma de criar botões
        self.botao = Button(self)
        self.botao['text'] = 'Bem vindo ao Python'
        self.botao['fg'] = 'red'
        self.botao['bg'] = 'yellow'
        self.botao.pack(side='top')

        # segunda forma de criar botões
        self.botao1 = Button(self, text='Segundo botão', fg='blue', bg='red')
        self.botao1.pack(side='top')

    def criarLabels(self):
        self.label = Label(self)
        self.label['text'] = 'Bem vindo ao Python'
        self.label.pack(side='top')

    def entradaDados(self):
        self.edit = Entry(self)
        self.edit.pack(side='top')


#criando a aplicação
minhaAplicacao = App()

minhaAplicacao.master.title('videoaulas Neri')
minhaAplicacao.master.maxsize(1024, 768)

#inicia a aplicação
minhaAplicacao.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

De maneira simples. Sua classe é herdeira de um frame e este frame deve ter uma janela onde ele irá se encaixar, o master significa exatamente isso, o local onde ele será colocado.

Deixando o argumento master como None significa que o frame será posicionado na janela principal (conhecida como root). Você também pode fazer isso com qualquer outro widget e apontar o master para um frame e etc.

Obs: Primeira vez postando aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Em tkinter os widgets são herdeiros de um frame, como por exemplo, eu posso criar um `Button` que fica dentro de um `Label` que fica dentro de um `Frame` que fica dentro da janela ( conhecida como root ou raiz ).

O parâmetro `master` é o local onde o widget será posicionado, como nesse exemplo abaixo:

```
from tkinter import *

def exit_button(master):
    button = Button(master,text="Sair",bg="red",fg="white")
    button.pack()

root = Tk()
exit_button(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Nesse exemplo, eu passo como argumento um objeto de Tk ( a janela do programa ), mas eu também poderia passar um `Frame` ou qualquer outra coisa para ser o local onde o botão de sair seria criado.

---

**O que acontece se eu deixar o master como None ?**

Quando não definimos um master para o frame, ele por padrão será criado na sua janela que é o "pai" de todos os frames.